# Unable to Join three Tables having Sum aggregate function using Sequelize libarary

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to join three table Organization_entries and users and user_invoices and I have a query like this in sql

```
select users.id ,users.name,users.email, users.mobile, sum(user_invoices.due_amount) , 
       organization_entries.id, organization_entries.created_at  
from users 
INNER JOIN user_invoices ON users.id = user_invoices.customer_id 
INNER JOIN organization_entries on users.id = organization_entries.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id, organization_entries.id 
ORDER BY organization_entries.created_at DESC;
```

This query is working fine and giving me desired result which I want but when I trying to convert this query using Sequelize libaray I am not able to understand how to convert this query in sequelize library .

I have tried something like this in Sequelize

```
db.users
    .findAll({
      where: condition,
      duplicating: false,
      attributes: [
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'mobile',
        'mobileAlternate',
        'image',
        'gender',
        'dob',
        'status',
        [
          db.sequelize.fn(
            'SUM',
            db.sequelize.col('userInvoices.due_amount')
          ),
          'dueAmount'
        ],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: db.userInvoices,
          attributes: ['dueAmount'],
        },
        {
          model: db.organizationEntries,
          attributes: ['id', 'fromDate', 'status', 'createdAt'],
          required: true,
          where: playerCondition,
          duplicating: false
        },

      ],
      group: ['users.id', 'organizationEntries.id'],
      order: [['organizationEntries', 'createdAt', 'DESC']],
      offset: pageCondition.startRecord,
      limit: pageCondition.endRecord
    })
```

but it is giving me this error
"Unknown column 'userInvoices.due_amount' in 'field list'",

This is the query which is genarated

"SELECT `users`.* FROM (SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`name`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`mobile`, `users`.`mobile_alternate` AS `mobileAlternate`, `users`.`image`, `users`.`gender`, SUM(`userInvoices`.`due_amount`) AS `amount`, `users`.`dob`, `users`.`status` FROM `users` AS `users` WHERE (`users`.`deleted_at` > '2018-02-27 15:22:30' OR `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) GROUP BY `users`.`id`, `organizationEntries`.`id` LIMIT 0, 20000) AS `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_invoices` AS `userInvoices` ON `users`.`id` = `userInvoices`.`customer_id` AND (`userInvoices`.`deleted_at` > '2018-02-27 15:22:30' OR `userInvoices`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)

Can any one please give me some hint how to write this query in Sequelize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
db.sequelize.col('userInvoices.due_amount')
```

to :

```
db.sequelize.col('user_invoices.due_amount')
```

Comment: change `attributes: ['dueAmount']`, to `attributes: []`, and try again

Comment: Hey I edited my question with the query generated by sequelize . Have a look at this